# x86 LOCK vs SFENCE/MFENCE

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86, intel

The x86 `LOCK` instruction allows a core to lock the system bus, so it can modify memory exclusively (or it allows the cache coherency protocol to achieve the same thing). However, Intel Developer Manual 3A doesn't state `LOCK` flushes the store buffer.

In contrast, `SFENCE` and `MFENCE` prevent re-ordering and flush the store buffer?

So when do I need to use `LOCK` and when `SFENCE`/`MFENCE`?

Does `LOCK` concern atomicity of a single instruction, whereas `SFENCE`/`MFENCE` concern a series of instructions?

Comment: SFENCE only orders NT stores against regular stores, and only *eventually* flushes the store buffer, but not before later loads can execute.  IDK why you'd even mention it in this context, except maybe on AMD CPUs where (I think) it has semantics more like MFENCE.

Comment: The only possible differences between a `lock`ed instruction and `mfence` are whether they order NT stores (yes) or weakly-ordered NT loads (in some cases no for locked).

Comment: So generally you only use mfence if you need a full barrier as part of something that isn't already an atomic RMW.  And if you're doing a store at all, it can be more efficient to use `xchg` instead of `mov + mfence`.  Of even to use a dummy `lock add qword [rsp], 0` instead of mfence.

Comment: @PeterCordes Given how powerful memory barriers are, I simply wasn't sure what the point of the LOCK instruction is.

Comment: Oh, `lock` gives you atomic RMW, as well as being a full barrier.  [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850)